# כְּהַיּוֹם vs. כַּיּוֹם

Tags: words, language, text, spelling-variants

Why does the word sometimes appear as כַּיּוֹם and sometimes as  כְּהַיּוֹם? As a general grammatical rule, a heh with a patach gets subsumed into the preceding kaf, so why are these cases different? Is there a difference in meaning or some sort of pattern? (As far as I know, כְּהַיּוֹם appears only 8 times in Tanach, while כַּיּוֹם appears much more often.)

One example of כְּהַיּוֹם appears in [Breishit 39:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=508&hilite=). Other examples appear in Devarim 6:24, Shmuel I 9:13, Yirmiyahu 44:22, Ezra 9:7, Ezra 9:15, Nechemia 5:11, and Nechemia 9:10.

For examples of כַּיּוֹם see Breishit 50:20, Devarim 2:30, Devarim 8:18, Shmuel I 22:8 etc.

Comment: I have seen the 2nd version in a few places. I think one occurrence is in the story where Joseph has problems with Potiphar's wife. If that's it, I'll try to edit that in. If you can find 1 or 2 examples of each version, please edit it into your question. It will make the research easier.

Comment: You might want to edit in that generally speaking כלב convert a succeeding ה prefix into a patach - and therefore כיום is the grammatically correct one.

Comment: כְּהַיּוֹם is probably an archaic vestige.